# Disable Fn + C OSX Monterey using Karabiner elements

Tags: keyboard, monterey, emacs

I'm an emacs user. I personalized my .emacs' file to uses Fn+C + C (C-c C-c)to evaluate buffers (more confortable for me); however, OSX Monterrey uses Fn+C to open Control Center, so I cannot run my emacs buffers. I didn't find any solution to disable Fn+C, so I'm trying with Karabiner-Elements, but it seems this only remap the key combination. Is it possible to remove the Fn+C combination for any OSX instruction and free it to be used only in emacs? Thanks

Here my config for the keys meta and control:

```
;; Change Meta for function
(setq mac-function-modifier 'control)
(setq mac-control-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-option-modifier nil) ;; free key alt
```

[image]

Comment: How are you using Fn + a letter to be a separately-recognised key command? Fn doesn't work as a modifier in that way, afaik.

Comment: In new OSX Monterrey this is predefined in accesibility commands: System Preferences -> Accesibility -> Keyboard -> Options -> Commands

Comment: Sorry, can't test. I don't have Monterey yet & can't find any reference to this online. Could you provide sample screenshots?

Comment: I edited the post to add a screenshot from the accesibility pane.

Comment: I'd wonder what is going on in the emacs config that's assigned eval-buffer to that key combination.  It's not a default.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain that I configured my .emacs file to use Fn as C- . I've edited the post with that part of my config.

Comment: FWIW I've done exactly the same thing and am in exactly the same position having just updated to Monterey...

Comment: I used Karabiner to make caps lock appear as f19 and then added f19 to do things to many keymaps in emacs. Basically the combination or karbiner and emacs can bind may things differently so you can do all sorts of thinmgs. A more plain emacs way might be to bind caps lock to Hyper in Karabinier

Answer (score 1):

This my temporal solution:

```
(setq mac-right-command-modifier 'control)
(setq mac-control-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-option-modifier nil) ;; free key alt
(setq mac-function-modifier 'control)
```

This only adds the right-Cmd as the control key, so you can use this when "Fn-XX" gets into conflict with emacs' keybindings. I hope anyone can come up with a real solution.